# AGPM and Production Delegation

Tags: group-policy

Advanced Group Policy Management (AGPM) and Production Delegation. The Production Delegation should set the delegation permissions on a GPO, i.e. Read, Edit, or Edit, Delete and Modify Security. In our new installation (4.3.160) it also creates a spurious "Apply" permission on the policy for the same trustee. This is obviously wrong. Just because the Domain Admins group has GpoEditDeleteModifySecurity permissions does not mean we want the policy to be applied to Domain Admins.
Does anyone have a current AGPM server where they could check this behaviour? It looks like a defect.